# How to see what rows are missing between two select statements in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a single table view that has a group column and a data column (among other columns).  In a particular group, there should be n rows of the same set of text in the same order.  However, I'm finding that in some groups, some rows are missing.  I'd like to query the view so that I can see what rows are missing.

Concrete example:

```
+--------+-------+
| Group  | Data  |
+--------+-------+
| 1      | row 1 |
| 1      | row 2 |
| 1      | row 3 |
| 2      | row 1 |
| 2      | row 3 |
+--------+-------+
```

Group 2 has "row 2" missing, and I'd like that output.  Something like:

```
+-------+
| Data  |
+-------+
| row 2 |
+-------+
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take the `COUNT` of Data column and then find count(Data) is less than Unique number of Group.

You can achieve it using below.

```
Select
Data,Count(*)
from tab
Group By Data
having Count(*)<(select count(Distinct Grp) from tab);
```

DB Fiddle: [Try it here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=d3a6cc49b2c5525171d57a78302c2204)

Comment: Nice! I've pushed the bar a bit higher with this next Q: [Can I generate a map that shows a particular row was in a particular group in SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72330589/can-i-generate-a-map-that-shows-a-particular-row-was-in-a-particular-group-in-sq).

Comment: Why count distinct Group? How is this related with existence of Data value in one or another group? Add one row with Group value '3' and Data value 'row 1' for example, and you will be surprised

Comment: @Abinash fiddle data doesn't match the question

Comment: INSERT INTO tab(Grp,Data) VALUES
 (1,'row 1'),(1,'row 2'),(1,'row 3'),
 (2,'row 1'),(1,'row 3');

Gives the wrong answer to this set of data. Doesn't show that group 2 is missing both row2 and row3.

Probably work if group_id and data are both unique

Comment: @nazim, This was the problem statement, , `I'd like to query the view so that I can see what rows are missing.`. He just wanted to view the rows which are having less data.

Comment: but the query is NOT giving the expected results for the set of different data in your sample. It doesn't show that row 3 is missing for group 2. Please observe that in your sample the last row is (1, row3) for group 1 not 2 - meaning the result of your query should list row 3 as missing for group 2 too

Comment: Thanks @nazim, the dataset was incorrect, corrected it. As per the problem statement each group will have same set of data, so we already know that there will be no duplicate data against the same group.