# Can I generate a map that shows a particular row was in a particular group in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Say I have the following data:

```
+--------+-------+
| Group  | Data  |
+--------+-------+
| 1      | row 1 |
| 1      | row 2 |
| 1      | row 3 |
| 20     | row 1 |
| 20     | row 3 |
| 10     | row 1 |
| 10     | row A |
| 10     | row 2 |
| 10     | row 3 |
+--------+-------+
```

Is it possible to draw a map that shows which groups have which rows?  Groups may not be contagious, so they can be placed into a separate table and use the row index for the string index instead. Something like this:

```
+-------+
| Group |
+-------+
| 1     |
| 20    |
| 10    |
+-------+

+-------+----------------+
| Data  | Found in group |
+-------+----------------+
| row 1 | 111            |
| row A |   1            |
| row 2 | 1 1            |
| row 3 | 111            |
+-------+----------------+
```

Where the first character represents Group 1, the 2nd is Group 20 and the 3rd is Group 10.

Ordering of the Group rows isn't critical so long as I can reference which row goes with which character.

I only ask this because I saw this [crazy example in the documentation generating a fractal](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html#outlandish_recursive_query_examples), but I can't quite get my head around it.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the missing values, first thing is to prepare a dataset which have all possible combination. You can achieve that using `CROSS JOIN`.

Once you have that DataSet, compare it with the actual DataSet.

Considering the Order by is done in the Grp column, you can achieve it using below.

```
SELECT
a.Data,group_concat(case when base.Grp is null then "." else "1" end,'') as Found_In_Group
,group_concat(b.Grp) as Group_Order
FROM
(SELECT Data FROM yourtable Group By Data)a
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT Grp FROM yourtable Group By Grp Order by Grp)b
LEFT JOIN yourtable base
ON  b.Grp=base.Grp
AND a.Data=base.Data
GROUP BY a.Data
```

Note: Considered `.` instead of blank for better visibility to represent missing Group.

| Data | Found_In_Group | Group_Order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| row 1 | 111 | 1,10,20 |
| row 2 | 11. | 1,10,20 |
| row 3 | 111 | 1,10,20 |
| row A | .1. | 1,10,20 |

Demo: [Try here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=9e6d4113306d38acf9d47deb1ace2534)

Comment: The only issue is that [the order of the concatenated elements is arbitrary](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#group_concat), which may require recursive cte as a workaround

Comment: Thanks @astentx for highlighting, but the ordering seems to be working if we order the result set in the subquery. But it(arbitrary ordering)  should be taken into consideration.

Comment: Wow! Nice! I wonder if any of this is done in parallel?  I have 50k groups and 2k data items. I wrote a single threaded perl script and it seemed to figure out one group in 12 sec, which would be roughly 6 days to process.  The bottleneck was the SQL line that extracted one group.

Comment: Well, the data looks great.  Processed it really fast (though I don't know how fast, it was way faster than my perl script).  sqlite3 doesn't seem to be using threads, but it is a real workhorse.  Thx for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT Data, group_concat("Group") AS "Found in group"
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY Data
```

will give you a CSV list of groups.

Comment: Close but not quite.  Missing the holes where the group doesn't have the data row.  See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=0a9f23abd1fb36c1bfb9c2302c37e227).

Comment: @Adrian You of course would have to adjust it to use your actual column names if they're different from what's in your post.

Comment: Of course, but that doesn't seem to be the problem.  I can live with the commas, but I need to have a hole where that group doesn't have the row.

Comment: @Adrian, Number of Groups are static or dynamic? As in, will there be always 3 groups (1,20,10) and What will be the order of the group?

Comment: @Abinash, I can force it to be static by finding all of the unique values, which will result in (1,20,10).  As for the order of the group, I'm not sure.  For now, we can leave it as undefined.